# Understanding derivatives in Isabelle (meaning of `at .. within`)

Tags: isabelle, derivative

This is a question about the notion of derivatives from the Isabelle libraries.

I am trying to understand what `(f has_field_derivative D x) (at x within S)` means. I know `(at x within S)` is a filter, but intuitively I was imagining that the following statement is true

```
lemma DERIV_at_within: 
"(∀x ∈ S. (f has_field_derivative D x) (at x)) 
   = (∀x. (f has_field_derivative D x) (at x within S))"
```

If it is not, how else should I interpret `(at x within S)` in the context of derivatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`at x within A` is the pointed neighbourhood of `x`, intersected with `A`. For instance, `at_right` is an abbreviation for `at x within {x<..}`, i.e. the right-neighbourhood of `x`. This allows you to express one-sided derivatives.

Occasionally, one also sees assumptions like `∀x∈{a..b}. (f has_field_derivative f' x) (at x within {a..b})`. This means that `f` is differentiable with derivative `f'` between `a` and `b`, but the derivatives at the edges (i.e. at `a` and `b`) need only be one-sided.

Note also that `at x = at x within UNIV`. Also, if `A` is an open set containint `x`, you simply have `at x within A = at x`.

Typically, you only really need `has_field_derivative` with `at x within …` if you want something like a one-sided limit (or, in higher dimensions, if you somehow want to constrain the direction of approach).

Comment: So the right side of my equation is stronger, and it would be provable if S were open?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be like this: for a given `x`, the statement `(f has_field_derivative D x) (at x within S)` means one of the following: If `x` is in the interior of `S`, it's the same as just writing `at x`. If `x` is not in the closure of `S`, it is completely vacuous (i.e. always true). Otherwise (i.e. if `x` is on the frontier of `S`), the `at x within S` statement is strictly weaker than the `at x` statement, but not vacuous either. It just describes a derivative with constrained approach.

Comment: Therefore, the statement on the right is generally not implied by the one on the left because the right says things about `x` that are on the frontier of `S` but not in `S` itself. On the other hand, the one on the left is also in general not implied by the one on the right because the one on the left makes a stronger statement about points that are on the frontier of `S` and that are in `S` itself as well. The right-hand side only says that the constrained-approach derivative exists; the one on the left makes no such restriction.